# Are const record arguments put on the stack?

Tags: delphi, stack

Suppose I have a record type called `TSomeRec`:

```
type
  TSomeRec = record
    // ...
  end;
```

... and a procedure that takes a const `TSomeRec` argument:

```
procedure SomeProc(const someRec: TSomeRec);
begin
  // ...
end;
```

When `SomeProc` is called, will the const `someRec` argument be passed on the stack as a value or as a reference?

The reason I ask is that in the code I am working on, the record type in question contains a massive static array and so is huge. (No, I cannot change that.) I am nervous about putting such a large record on the stack, and I thought that `const` might help. I have had problems with this code with overflowing the stack, and when that happens, I just get mysterious access violations rather than any sort of stack overflow error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends. This is actually described in the online help, but here goes.

In 32 bit Windows executables (i.e. code compiled with WIN32 defined), if the record is not larger than a 32 bit register, it is pushed on the stack as-is, i.e. *passed by value*. If the record is larger than a register, a pointer to the record is passed, i.e. *passed by reference*. That is for the default `register` calling convention. It may be different for other platforms or calling conventions, but the above is very likely the general case.

[DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Parameters_(Delphi)):

> Constant parameters may be passed to the function by value or by reference, depending on the specific compiler used. To force the compiler to pass a constant parameter by reference, you can use the [Ref] decorator with the const keyword.

[But see the Delphi Language Guide too](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Program_Control_(Delphi)#Passing_Parameters). It describes how all kinds of parameters are passed, e.g.

> Sets, records, and static arrays of 1, 2, or 4 bytes are passed as 8-bit, 16-bit, and 32bit values. Larger sets, records, and static arrays are passed as 32-bit pointers to the value. An exception to this rule is that records are always passed directly on the stack under the cdecl, stdcall, and safecall conventions; the size of a record passed this way is rounded upward to the nearest double-word boundary.

That has changed for newer compilers, though.

But to be sure, you can always consult the CPU view. There you can see what happens.

Comment: Thanks. This is Delphi 2007, so it doesn't have `[Ref]`. The default calling convention is "register", so that should means the record will be passed by reference according to your second link. (So long as there aren't more than three parameters, I guess, given the limitations of "register".) I guess to be absolutely sure I could explicitly pass a pointer the record myself.

Comment: In the `register` calling convention, if the record is larger than 4 bytes, it will be passed by reference, no matter if it is the first or the seventh parameter. But if it is the first, the pointer will be passed in a register (`EAX`). If it is the seventh, the pointer will be passed on the stack.

Comment: FWIW, it helps if you consult the CPU view. That will clearly show you what happens.

Comment: Thanks. That's interesting about the pointer being passed on the stack. I tried to look at the CPU view, but my x86 knowledge is very limited, and the CPU stack view is just a raw hex dump, so I couldn't make much sense of it.

Comment: FWIW, large records are not passed directly on the stack in non-const either. But for non-const call by value, a pointer is passed to the function, and in the startup code (prolog) of the function, that pointer is used to copy that record to the local frame of the function, before the written code is entered. When passed as const, that copy is not made, because the record can not be modified anyway (well, except with its own methods, but that is a different story), so the original can be used. That is why const can make function calls faster.

Comment: So in register calling convention a non-const record will take up storage on the stack.

Comment: Win32 actually covers both 32 and 64 bit processes. The 32 is there to disambiguate from the 16 bit Windows API which became known as Win16.  Rather than Win32 what you mean is "in a 32 bit Windows process".

Comment: @dan-gph: Yes. Only a pointer is passed, but inside the function, the content of the record is copied to the local stack frame. It *must* be copied, to avoid inadvertently overwriting the original record. That would be against the principles of "pass by value": you must be able to modify the local copy without modifying the original. With const, you are prevented from **directly** writing to the original (you can write to it indirectly, e.g. through immutable methods, or using pointer tricks), so there, a reference to the original is considered good enough.

Comment: The point is that Win32 describes the API and the API is the same between 32 and 64 bit. It's very common to use Win32 for both 32 and 64 bit processes. So it's clearer to say 32 bit Windows process.

Comment: @David: yes, I see what you mean. I already modified the answer a bit.